# Mongodb sort on array of objects inside a document only on those objects where a key matches a certain value

Tags: mongodb, sorting

I have a mongo document which looks like the following

```
{
    "formId": "b5d65e0c-bc3e-451c-8e2e-34796fd93f7d",
    "data": [{
        "label": "MaterialDocument",
        "key": "MaterialDocument",
        "uuid": "7f249dea-b51b-435f-b5a4-912bb914c0b5",
        "value": 0,
        "isMetricField": true,
        "unitOfMeasurement": "5ef1b42f2aa78e1211b3e23a",
        "dataCaptureStart": 1604169000000,
        "dataCaptureEnd": 1604169000000
    }, {
        "label": "MaterialDocItem",
        "key": "MaterialDocItem",
        "uuid": "07fd9f63-e093-4d28-86a6-8acf85d3d7da",
        "value": "0000",
        "isMetricField": false,
        "dataCaptureStart": 1604169000000,
        "dataCaptureEnd": 1604169000000
    }, {
        "label": "Material",
        "key": "Material",
        "uuid": "fa3f4e76-8464-47e5-9727-2f967101c98c",
        "value": "0",
        "isMetricField": false,
        "dataCaptureStart": 1604169000000,
        "dataCaptureEnd": 1604169000000
    }, {
        "label": "Plant",
        "key": "Plant",
        "uuid": "70d49be5-79a3-4e5c-9f96-080b480e564f",
        "value": "0",
        "isMetricField": false,
        "dataCaptureStart": 1604169000000,
        "dataCaptureEnd": 1604169000000
    }, {
        "label": "StorageLocation",
        "key": "StorageLocation",
        "uuid": "2def5e2c-7a74-4c24-940d-5b491e94e3a4",
        "value": "0",
        "isMetricField": false,
        "dataCaptureStart": 1604169000000,
        "dataCaptureEnd": 1604169000000
    }, {
        "label": "MovementType",
        "key": "MovementType",
        "uuid": "2bdb3468-5b9b-4f92-acd8-777eb6afbc73",
        "value": "0",
        "isMetricField": false,
        "dataCaptureStart": 1604169000000,
        "dataCaptureEnd": 1604169000000
    }, {
        "label": "PostingDate",
        "key": "PostingDate",
        "uuid": "3867444c-f607-481a-88a0-9777ad50fa83",
        "value": "2020-11-01T00:00:00",
        "isMetricField": false,
        "dataCaptureStart": 1604169000000,
        "dataCaptureEnd": 1604169000000
    }, {
        "label": "Production Count",
        "key": "QuantityInUnitOfEntry",
        "uuid": "53a58b51-8d29-41e6-b83c-2dd6dc394154",
        "value": 0,
        "isMetricField": true,
        "unitOfMeasurement": "5ef1b42f2aa78e1211b3e239",
        "dataCaptureStart": 1604169000000,
        "dataCaptureEnd": 1604169000000
    }, {
        "label": "Department",
        "key": "Department",
        "uuid": "eafcb451-9d09-4c90-b20b-621aa06db684",
        "value": "",
        "isMetricField": false,
        "dataCaptureStart": 1604169000000,
        "dataCaptureEnd": 1604169000000
    }, {
        "label": "UnitOfEntry",
        "key": "UnitOfEntry",
        "uuid": "6b64a824-0586-4b02-afbc-8e9190b5ce26",
        "value": "EA",
        "isMetricField": false,
        "dataCaptureStart": 1604169000000,
        "dataCaptureEnd": 1604169000000
    }],
    "dataCaptureDate": 1604169000000,
    "addedBy": "a307473b-92b3-4429-92c8-cf11ece428e4",
    "uuid": "9583a3bf-b9a7-47a5-8455-ff1901ead3bd",
    "addedTimestamp": 1607361597,
    "updatedTimestamp": 1607361597
}
```

There are other similar documents in the same collection and I am performing aggregation operation on them to get their list.

I want to sort on "value" key inside the data array. But I only want to perform sort on those "value" where the "uuid" matches a certain value.

For example I do not want to perform sorting on all "value" keys of all documents but lets say perform sort only on "value" where "uuid" == "07fd9f63-e093-4d28-86a6-8acf85d3d7da" (the second object in data array).

Is this type of sorting possible in mongodb where we do not perform sort blindly on all keys but with an additional condition as well?

Expected output looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5fce64684a37150009c833cd",
    "formId": "b5d65e0c-bc3e-451c-8e2e-34796fd93f7d",
    "data": [{
            "label": "MaterialDocument",
            "key": "MaterialDocument",
            "uuid": "7f249dea-b51b-435f-b5a4-912bb914c0b5",
            "value": 6001038542,
            "isMetricField": true,
            "unitOfMeasurement": "5ef1b42f2aa78e1211b3e23a",
            "dataCaptureStart": 1602873000000,
            "dataCaptureEnd": 1602873000000,
            "uomName": "Numbers"
        },
        {
            "label": "MaterialDocItem",
            "key": "MaterialDocItem",
            "uuid": "07fd9f63-e093-4d28-86a6-8acf85d3d7da",
            "value": "0001",
            "isMetricField": false,
            "dataCaptureStart": 1602873000000,
            "dataCaptureEnd": 1602873000000
        },
        {
            "label": "Material",
            "key": "Material",
            "uuid": "fa3f4e76-8464-47e5-9727-2f967101c98c",
            "value": "24AR040C01",
            "isMetricField": false,
            "dataCaptureStart": 1602873000000,
            "dataCaptureEnd": 1602873000000
        },
        {
            "label": "Plant",
            "key": "Plant",
            "uuid": "70d49be5-79a3-4e5c-9f96-080b480e564f",
            "value": "1604",
            "isMetricField": false,
            "dataCaptureStart": 1602873000000,
            "dataCaptureEnd": 1602873000000
        },
        {
            "label": "StorageLocation",
            "key": "StorageLocation",
            "uuid": "2def5e2c-7a74-4c24-940d-5b491e94e3a4",
            "value": "TH50",
            "isMetricField": false,
            "dataCaptureStart": 1602873000000,
            "dataCaptureEnd": 1602873000000
        },
        {
            "label": "MovementType",
            "key": "MovementType",
            "uuid": "2bdb3468-5b9b-4f92-acd8-777eb6afbc73",
            "value": "131",
            "isMetricField": false,
            "dataCaptureStart": 1602873000000,
            "dataCaptureEnd": 1602873000000
        },
        {
            "label": "PostingDate",
            "key": "PostingDate",
            "uuid": "3867444c-f607-481a-88a0-9777ad50fa83",
            "value": "2020-10-17T00:00:00",
            "isMetricField": false,
            "dataCaptureStart": 1602873000000,
            "dataCaptureEnd": 1602873000000
        },
        {
            "label": "Production Count",
            "key": "QuantityInUnitOfEntry",
            "uuid": "53a58b51-8d29-41e6-b83c-2dd6dc394154",
            "value": 120,
            "isMetricField": true,
            "unitOfMeasurement": "5ef1b42f2aa78e1211b3e239",
            "dataCaptureStart": 1602873000000,
            "dataCaptureEnd": 1602873000000,
            "uomName": "PPM"
        },
        {
            "label": "Department",
            "key": "Department",
            "uuid": "eafcb451-9d09-4c90-b20b-621aa06db684",
            "value": "",
            "isMetricField": false,
            "dataCaptureStart": 1602873000000,
            "dataCaptureEnd": 1602873000000
        },
        {
            "label": "UnitOfEntry",
            "key": "UnitOfEntry",
            "uuid": "6b64a824-0586-4b02-afbc-8e9190b5ce26",
            "value": "EA",
            "isMetricField": false,
            "dataCaptureStart": 1602873000000,
            "dataCaptureEnd": 1602873000000
        }
    ],
    "dataCaptureDate": 1602873000000,
    "addedBy": "a307473b-92b3-4429-92c8-cf11ece428e4",
    "uuid": "90dd4950-4535-4a06-9c87-e8784c7379d1",
    "addedTimestamp": 1607361640,
    "updatedTimestamp": 1607361640,
    "formName": "Movement Type 131 - Form",
    "formRecordId": "5fc8c9f7123c340009af7785",
    "addedByName": "Rivas Ochoa",
    "department": "HQ"
},
  {...}
]
```

The expected output is the same collection you see but with some added params, thats it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can please you add expected output.

Comment: There is no direct feature which address this issue.

Comment: Added an expected output.

Comment: that id is still in second position when we compare with your expected result. i can not see any difference in expected result.

Comment: I want to perform sorting on all the documents within that collection not on the individual documents data array. so if there are 100 such documents, i want to get list of them all sort by the "value" where uuid has a certain value

Comment: still its unclear, when uuid had certain value match then sort by "value" field either that document come first or last? see [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/o_ec6H5Wr76) if i am not wrong.